Is a Biologist on Cognitive Sciences SE welcomed as a reviewer?
Being a Neuroscientist with a Biology background I am most active on Biology SE. However, Cognitive Sciences SE also features many interesting questions with awesome answers that differ in interesting ways from the, for me so typical, Biological vantage points. Hence, I find Cognitive Sciences SE rewarding and interesting. Nonetheless, my expertise is mostly in Biology. Now I am approaching the 1k point in Cognitive Sciences SE (being active for not more than a few months, so I am pretty much a newbie I guess) and this will unlock the remainder of review queues. As of now I review what I can and skip what I can't (pretty much fifty-fifty I think) but I think it is appropriate to ask the Cognitive Science community directly:
Are reviews from a Biologist-Neuroscientist appreciated or should I refrain from reviewing? 

I see no problem at all, especially when you state: "As of now I review what I can and skip what I can't (pretty much fifty-fifty I think)" Just decide on what you feel qualified to decide on, and leave the rest to others. Glad to have you on board!

You have had a meteoric rise in reputation on both sites, and you have a great "head" for knowing what's on-topic, etc. Combined with the fact that you have an excellent grasp on the subject matter, I'd say that we'd be foolish to tell you to hold back.

@ChuckSherrington - Thank you for these encouraging words. I will go for it then! Please don't hold back in giving feedback.

Yes, you are absolutely welcome to review. We all have different backgrounds, but I think that is a useful thing on this site.
